# Find a part of UNC path and put in a variable?

Tags: c#, .net, string

I am trying to peel off the last part of a unc path that is being passed and put it in a variable to use in a method further down the line.

Example path would be --> `\\ourfileserver\remoteuploads\countyfoldername\personfoldername`

How do I peel just the `countyfoldername` out of that?

I had thought to try

```
var th = e.FullPath.LastIndexOf('\\');
        var whichFolder = folderPath.Substring(th);
```

but that is an escape character and it doesn't like `@` either.

Is this even the right direction?

---

I think I have confused some of you.  `LastIndexOf` doesn't work because I need the `countyfoldername` which, in my example, occurs 3/4 of the way through.

Also, I need the `countyfoldername` stored in a variable, not the file name itself.

To give some context, I have a `FileSystemWatcher` that runs in a service.  It was monitoring a single folder path and emailing when a file was created there.  Now I need to modify it.  There are now 4 county folders at that folder path and I need to send an email to a different email address depending on where a file is created.

I can use a simple switch statement if I can figure out how to get the county folder name reliably.

Thanks

Comment: Your updated code should work, I've used it many times.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, you should use the Uri Class and break it into segments.

```
    Uri uri = new Uri(@"\\ourfileserver\remoteuploads\countyfoldername\personfoldername");
    Console.WriteLine(uri.Segments[3]); // personfoldername
    Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: PS: When you fetch a Segment, it is in escaped format. E.g. "My Folder" would appear as "My%20Folder". One needs to call the static method Uri.UnescapeDataString to get the actual name.

Answer (score 2):

string folder = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fullpath)

Full docs [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Did you try:

```
var myCounty = e.FullPath.LastIndexOf("\\");
```

Update:
In order to get the country folder name, just trim off the number of characters found from the county look up, then do another last index of..

Comment: single of double quotes there?  just checking as don't char's use single?  Thanks

Comment: doesn't lastindexof return an integer? wouldn't he need to grab the substring starting at the lastindexof?

Comment: yes my plan was to do something like this --> `var th = e.FullPath.LastIndexOf('\\');
            var whichFolder = folderPath.Substring(th);` unless there was a better way...

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a substring from LastIndexOf("\")

Looks something like:

```
var folderName = e.FullPath.Substring(e.FullPath.LastIndexOf("\\"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should split.

```
string[] Sep= {"\\"}

string[] Folders;
Folders= folderPath.Split(NewLine, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

You can traverse the array and hace full control over the string.